# Add space between italic/smallcaps glyph and upright parenthesis

Tags: spacing, luatex, brackets, kerning

I'm typesetting a document where unavoidably there are upright parentheses in the middle of italic or smallcaps words, like *th*(*is*) `\textit{th}(\textit{is})` (or the same with `\textsc`). In only these cases I would like to insert a little extra space between the opening parenthesis and the preceding letter in order to improve their appearance, as they often come close to colliding. Is there a way to do this systematically? I'm using LuaLaTeX.

It would be much more preferable to do this by changing the preamble rather than by changing the document itself.

Comment: `\textit` already provides italic correction... Compare with `\itshape`: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\textit{th}(\textit{is})\par
{\itshape th}(\textit{is})
\end{document}`.

Comment: @frougon For the font I'm using, the italic correction is not big enough, I suppose. And it is compounded by the fact that the text is being set at a small point size.

Answer (score 2):

You might use the `embrac` package which

- allows you to use normal input `\textit{th(is)}` and
- gives you an interface for the adaption of the kerning.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embrac}

\begin{document}

\textit{th(is)}

\ChangeEmph{(}[-.12em,.05em]{)}[-.05em,-.15em]    
\textit{th(is)}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll look into this, but a solution which doesn't require me to rewrite parts of the document section would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
You have

\textit{th}(\textit{is})

You may use

\textit{th}\,(\textit{is})

%\, may be replaced by any skip

but rather as a macro. Say

\def\AAA#1#2{\textit{#1}\,(\textit{#2})}
\verb+\def\AAA#1#2{\textit{#1}\,(\textit{#2})}+

with usage

\AAA{th}{is}

\end{document}
```